# wso2 truncates the jms destination path

Tags: wso2

I'm running the example from http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2011/11/configuring-wso2-esb-with-oracle-as-messaging-media/

Once the proxy is defined it works as intended, i.e. it reads a messages from the queue and places the SOAP call.
However, if the proxy is re-opened and saved wso2 starts spinning spitting out errors:

```
java.naming.security.credentials=tromanow}
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 -   INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: ERR_229 Cannot authenticate user ]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3087)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3033)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2835)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2749)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:316)
```

The problem is that the JMS destination LDAP path gets truncated.
From:

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">cn=tro_Q_JMS1,cn=OracleDBQueues,cn=ORCL,cn=OracleContext,ou=Services, o=sgi,c=us</parameter>
```

To:

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">cn=tro_Q_JMS1</parameter>
```

The workaround is to re-append the rest of the LDAP path to the JMS destination whenever saving the proxy. Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a UI bug related to the UI editor library used by WSO2 ESB management console. You can do the changes in the file system using the xml file and save. Then it will saved successfully. If you are using developer studio, then you can deploy artifacts as CAR (Composite Archive) files and you do not need to change them from the UI.